# Are Android Roms Using Custom Kernel Configs?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, rom

So just wondering. Are all the Android Roms custom made for each device? I mean, is it like a Gentoo like configuration where you compile the linux kernel with all the stuff that you need instead of using a generic one?

Answer (score 3):

That is the current state of things, indeed. Embedded devices are so specific that each of them comes with its own board configuration file (in arch/arm/mach-xxx) where its devices layout is hardcoded. The device tree effort tries to fix that, but we are still very far from the x86 situation where one kernel can boot all machines.

Another incentive for having a tailor-made kernel is to reduce its memory footprint and avoid putting hundreds of unused kernel modules on the limited storage space.